# How to select very first non-null date BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition, row-number

I want to select very first non-null datetime but it doesn't work for me with using

> "row_number() over partition()"

In my code now I just excluded null rows and now I need to select only the lowest date.
Pls.help how to fix it:

```
left join (
          select deal, type, assigned_to_user, marked_as_done_time,
          first_value(marked_as_done_time ignore nulls) over (partition by deal
          order by marked_as_done_time asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as first_value,
          
          from data_marts.pipedrive_activity
          where done = 'Done' 
          group by 1,2,3,4
          ) act on act.deal = d.id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  There might be a simpler way to write this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
left join (
          select deal, type, assigned_to_user, marked_as_done_time,
          row_number() over (partition by deal
          order by marked_as_done_time) as first_value,
          
          from data_marts.pipedrive_activity
          where done = 'Done' and marked_as_done_time is not null
          group by 1,2,3,4
          ) act on act.deal = d.id where first_value=1
```